# Is it possible to get Android App category from .apk files?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, categories

I have an `.apk` file. And I want to know that which category the app belongs (**category example: Gaming, Entertainment, Sports, etc**).

FYI: Google Play services to get category of an `apk` is not required. Some other feasible solution is welcome.

Comment: search app name on Google play

Comment: You can parse Manifest.xml and then find out some information about which permission used and guess Category but I think it's  too hard to guess !

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I want to know from apk file not google play.

Comment: @Tej: Category is not part of APK File is part of Google Play then how we are able to know it from APK???

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to retrieve a Play Store category ***directly*** from the .apk file.

However, you can scan the contents of the .apk file programmatically by searching for keywords in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `Strings.xml`

In an Android application, you can

`exec("cat /sdcard/unzippedapk/res/Strings.xml | grep -i game OR sports OR social media")`

and measure the output to see if there are matches.

**Your other option** is to grab the package name, and query `play.google.com` and parse the HTML:

HTTP Get: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.XXXX.XXXXX&hl=en`

Relevant HTML segment:

```
<span itemprop="genre">Productivity</span>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Then you'll have to go with option A and unzip the apk, search Strings.xml and Manifest for clues, whether that be manually or programmatically.

Comment: Hey, it works well, but what if google play is in other language? How to get only english version of category?